# RxJava- Listen to coming Observable periodically

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have an xml file deployed in server.How can listen to it each 10 seconds to check if it exists and process it after using RxJava ? could you give please the operator name

Answer (score 0):

Something like that I suppose -

```
Observable<Int>.interval(1.0, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance).flatMap { _ -> return YourService.request(); }
```